# Stripe: Customize error page of expiration checkout session

Tags: stripe-payments, checkout, stripes

When the Stripe checkout session expires, an error message appears with no possibility for any action for example a back button to take the user back to our website.
My question is how to add a back button to the error page and customize the error message.

- The first image is from my setting and the second one is what I want to achieve.
  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to customise the expired session page.

Instead, you should configure [abandoned cart recovery](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/abandoned-carts) which can assist by generating a new session URL for your customers to visit once the original session expires.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I have updated my question. I need to make it similar to image 2 with a clear message and a Back button (a possibility to redirect user to my website)

Comment: As stated, that cannot be customised.